# Git pre-receive hook newRev issue

Tags: git, githooks

While executing pre-receive hook `git show $newrev` shows diff in `$newRev` but if while executing `pre-receive` hook I will go to repo and execute the same command `git show $newrev` it will return error `fatal: bad object {newRev}`.

Git version: 2.22.0. On Git 2.7.4 executing `git show` in repo doesn't return error.

`pre-receive hook script` when `git show` works correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read oldrev newrev refname

git show $newrev
```

`pre-receive hook script` with sleep and manually run `git show` in repo

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read oldrev newrev refname

sleep 999
```

```
cd /repo
git show ae435ae1f9de55620d306cc82799ff20870f4238
```

fatal: bad object ae435ae1f9de55620d306cc82799ff20870f4238

Answer (score 1):

After investigating I understood that Git in `pre-receive` hook creates separate temp dir where it collects info about commit that came. For example temp dir name is `objects/incoming-GsAsa`.

But Git knew about it only in `pre-receive` hook script because it set `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` and `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` envs properly.

So, the answer for the question is to set properly `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` and `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` vars.